# How to calculate the number of rows (& their percentage) that fall below the 10th percentile of column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum, percentile-cont

I have a column with numbers. I already calculated the percentiles using percentile_cont. How can I sum up/count all the rows (& calculate their %) that fall below, e.g. the 25th percentile?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER
Example:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
     [PARTITION BY expr1, expr2,...]
     ORDER BY expr1 [ASC | DESC], expr2,...
 )
 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Id) AS RowNumber, Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM User
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Row number just assigns a sequence integer based on the partition and order. By itself it doesn't address much of OP's question.

Comment: when you calculate the percentage, also calculate the number of rows

Comment: `(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by (count(*)))) * 100 / (count(*) over ()) as Percentage`

Comment: yes something like this                                                                                 valuecolumn < PERCENTILE_CONT(.1) within group (order by valuecolumn) OVER (PARTITION somegroup) as SMALLER10 (at least that would give me the rows)